# Are there any compiler development forums?

Tags: compiler-construction

I am interested in in joining an already established compiler or interpreter development project but I haven't found any useful resources so far. I'm looking for something that has a smallish development team and where the work will be substantial (i.e. not working on bug fixes). SourceForge of course has a lot of projects but it definitely takes a while to find what projects are still active and might still fit. So that's why I was thinking about possible forums that might have something. I searched on Google but didn't really find anything.

Thanks ahead of time for anyone's input

Answer (score 5):

Try usenet. comp.compilers

Comment: very low traffic and moderated, so don't expect a vibrant community there

Answer (score 1):

We need substantial help on the [c--](http://www.cminusminus.org/) project.  There is so much to do you can practically write your own ticket: are you interested in front ends, code generators, optimizations, garbage collector, or run-time systems?

Answer (score 0):

There are many compiler projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=compiler&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1).